# Slider Thumb.DragStarted event does not fire or call method when using event trigger

Tags: wpf, events, slider, expression-blend, interaction

Below is my xaml:

```
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Thumb.DragDelta" >
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="AudioTimeSliderDragDelta" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Thumb.DragCompleted">
                        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="AudioTimeSliderDragCompleted" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
```

Although i am able to invoke slider MouseMove event, Somehow the dragEvent handler events doesn't get fired, hence the related methods never gets executed. 
I have tried DragEnter as well. Dint work.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that all these "event to command", "Event Triggers" (that call methods) and all that stuff is just bloat and overengineering for people who initially thought using code behind in WPF was wrong. Remove that and handle the event from code behind, and then call whatever methods you need from the VM, at the event handler. Unless this XAML is in a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I eventually removed event to command approach. It was sure bloating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Binding of the slider value to be triggered by PropertyChanged so you will get an update for every value change. So if the user dragged the slider from 1 to 100 you will get 100 updates which will be the behavior you were after.